# Get UID and document data Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a Collection with 6 fields and the collection has 4 documents with unique UID. I'm able to fetch the data and display it with List view.

I tried using document snapshot, when i print $docSnapshot all i get is Instance of Document snapshot.
Am i missing something? I want to fetch the UID and data of each document in the collection.

```
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> petData = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Data').doc().snapshots();
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: petData,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) 
   

 {
       DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = snapshot.data; 
    }
      )
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of what you are getting ?

Comment: I added the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

[DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) has a method [`data()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) that retrieves all fields in the document as a Map.

Try adding this line in your builder to check if it works:

```
print(snapshot.data.data())
```

Comment: print(snapshot.data.data())  returned the UID of user who is logged in and not the document's UID